# return a local pointer

Tags: c++, local-variables

```
struct node
{
  Item item; node *l, *r;
  node(Item x) {item = x; l = 0; r = 0;}
};

typedef node* link;
link max(Item a[], int l, int r)
{
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    link x = new node(a[m]);
    if (l==r) return x; // return a local pointer
    x->l = max(a, l, m);
    x-r = max(a, m+1, r);
    Item u = x->l->item, v = x->r->item;
    if (u>v) x->item = u;
    else x->item=v;

    return x;    // return a local pointer
}
```

This is a piece of code from "Algorithm in c++" by Robert Sedgewick, page 252, Program 5.19. And in function `max()`, the returned variable is a pointer which is created inside the function.

In my opinion, returning a local pointer is not allowed in c/c++. So my question is that "is that OK to write a function like this"? I cannot believe such a classic book make mistake like this. Or I misunderstood the principle?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `link x = new node(a[m]);` != local pointer

Comment: @Mysticial: Pedantically speaking, it *is* a local pointer, but it doesn't point to a local object :-)

Comment: In `c` returning a pointer to a local variable with result in a warning, and probably should be avoided unless you know what you're doing, but it will work. Not sure is `c++` changes that into an error.

Comment: @twain249: It's not an error in C++. Are you saying that the C standard mandates a diagnostic? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @KerrekSB I just made a function like this `int *fun() { int a = 3; return &a;}` and compiled it, using gcc, to see what would happen and I got a warning. So I guess all I can say for sure is that gcc causes a warning for this.

Comment: @twain249: That's all very edifying, but I don't think that "proof-by-that's-what-my-compiler-does" will pass for a statement about the C standard :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree it's not a proof about the C standard that's why I qualified it in my second comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` isn't a "local pointer" - that is, a pointer to a local variable.  `*x` was allocated using `new`. `x` points to dynamically allocated memory and returning that pointer is just fine.  So yes, it's OK to write a function like this one, and there's not an error in the book.

Answer (score 4):

It is an error to return a pointer to a local variable. `x` points to a variable allocated on the heap:

```
link x = new node(a[m]);
```

Thus `x` isn't pointing to a local variable.

The reason that returning a pointer to a local variable is an error is that such a variable exists for only as long as the function is active (i.e. between it is entered and exited). Variables allocated on the heap (e.g. with the use of the `new` operator) exist until they are deallocated (e.g. with the `delete` operator).

Comment: So the memory allocated to x will not be freed until we explicitly do so. Or can I say memory allocated on function stack will be undefined if the variable goes out of scope; but on heap will not?

Comment: Yes. You do need explicit deallocation. Also, a variable allocated on the heap will continue to exist after returning from the function which allocated it.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, because the contents of `x` are allocated on the heap, not the stack. You might be getting confused since there is a `typedef node* link;` in there, making it look like a stack allocation since it masks the fact that `x` is actually a `node *`.

Comment: `x` is an automatic variable. You were maybe thinking about `*x`.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah I suppose I meant "the contents of `x` are allocated on the heap", edited for clarity.

Comment: Actually, the contents of `x` are the contents of an automatic variable. You were maybe thinking about the contents of `*x`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess we have differing definitions of "the contents", and I guess yours is probably the more correct one.